# MongoDB drivers won't install through Nuget

Tags: c#, mongodb, visual-studio, nuget

I am trying to install the latest MongoDB drivers through Nuget. I have also attempted through the Package Manager Console, but getting an issue. I am using...

Visual Studio 2013
MVC4.5 (I have upgraded to 4.5.2)
MongoDB drivers version 2.11.1
MongoDB 4.4.0 Community

Initially, it was saying that it won't install for MVC4.5 and I was reluctant to upgrade (due to upgrade issues I have had in the past). I made a backup and upgraded to 4.5.2

Now, I am getting an error...

> Attempting to resolve dependency 'MongoDB.Bson (≥ 2.11.1)'. Attempting
> to resolve dependency 'MongoDB.Driver.Core (≥ 2.11.1)'. Part URI
> cannot start with two forward slashes.

I have installed MongoDB.Bson individually fine.

If I try to install MongoDB.Driver.Core by itself, I get a different error...

> Attempting to resolve dependency 'MongoDB.Bson (≥ 2.11.1)'. Part URI
> cannot start with two forward slashes.

If I attempt to install MongoDB.Libmongocrypt, then I get this error...

> Installing 'MongoDB.Libmongocrypt 1.0.0'. Successfully installed
> 'MongoDB.Libmongocrypt 1.0.0'. Adding 'MongoDB.Libmongocrypt 1.0.0' to
> Portal. Uninstalling 'MongoDB.Libmongocrypt 1.0.0'. Successfully
> uninstalled 'MongoDB.Libmongocrypt 1.0.0'. Install failed. Rolling
> back... Invalid static method invocation syntax:
> "[MSBuild]::IsOsPlatform('Windows')". Method '[MSBuild]::IsOsPlatform'
> not found. Static method invocation should be of the form:
> $([FullTypeName]::Method()), e.g. $([System.IO.Path]::Combine(`a`,
> `b`)).   C:\Users\david\Documents\Visual Studio
> 2013\Projects\Portal\Portal\packages\MongoDB.Libmongocrypt.1.0.0\build\MongoDB.Libmongocrypt.targets

How do I get the drivers installed?

Comment: Hi David, any update about this issue? Please check if my answer helps you handle the issue. If it helps, please do not forget to accept it and if not, please let us know any feedback or your concern about this issue:)

Comment: Hi Perry, I have not had the opportunity yet to do as you have suggested. I will try and get to it today. My only concern is that if I upgrade VS, is will it have any effect on my codebase? In the past, when I have done that, I have spent days fixing things that should never have broken.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and actually, the latest VS2019 supports the old project. And basically there will be no major issues, just in case, you can back up your project. See [this official project migration and upgrade document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/porting/port-migrate-and-upgrade-visual-studio-projects?view=vs-2019).

Comment: If you want to use this new version of the nuget, use VS2019 and migrate your project is the only one. If there are several problems, it is inevitable, after all, VS2013 is too old. Otherwise,  you should install the old version of the nuget pakage just as I recommended. Anyway, we will wait for your feedback and give you any support if you want.

Comment: From the upgrade document, it states that no new MVC4 projects can be created. This could be a problem... and when I tried to use MVC5 in the past, there were too many differences for me to get my head around. If I update to VS2019, will the project still open in VS2013 so that I can add new projects? Also, when I copy my project to live, am I likely to be missing anything? (this is MVC4)

Comment: The VS2019 still support VS2013 MVC 4 project as the document said, you could directly open your vs2013 project in VS2019 IDE. You did not bother it too much but It is indeed possible that some functions will be lost. When you upgrade your project into VS2019 and then install that package, you cannot move it back to VS2013 since VS does not support downgrades.

Comment: As a suggestion, make a backup of your old project. Then, create a new net framework 4.5.2 mvc project in VS2019 and then migrate the content of your old project into the new one. This will save much time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MongoDB drivers won't install through Nuget

You have installed the latest version of [MongoDB.Driver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver/2.11.1) on your old **VS2013**. The latest version `MongoDB.Driver 2.11.1` is released recently(2020.8.25) and is not compatible with the **nuget package manager** of the old **VS2013** while it could be compatible with the latest VS IDE.

**Also, VS2013** is so old that **Microsoft** no longer maintains it.

**Suggestion**

**1)** you should install an older version of the nuget package `MongoDB.Driver` which is compatible with the **nuget package manager** of the old **VS2013**.

try to install version `2.3.0`.

Run this command under **Package Manager Console**:

```
Install-Package MongoDB.Driver -Version 2.3.0
```

**2)** install [the latest VS2019 Community Version(free)](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/) and open your project with VS2019.

**Then**, you can install the latest nuget package and will not encounter the problem of not being able to install the package due to the compatibility of the nuget packages which from the old VS2013's nuget package manager.

Comment: Once upgraded to VS2019, I had to update my EntitiyFramework nuget package on all my projects. Also had to ensure all projects were .NET 4.5.2 (as it was not fully building - Build Failed). I also found for some reason that my web.config in my views folder on my main project had become corrupt. Copied the one from my backup and it then worked.